# Need to make an Invoice Number Generator in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I need to make an Invoice code with the following template :

INV-YYYYMMDDXXXXX (XXXXX = 5 digit running number)

Then, I write these codes in my 'store' in the Controller

```
$inv = 'INV-';
$invcode = $request->$inv.date().$invnum;
$invnum = $invnum + 1;
```

Then I write :

```
$array  = [
    'InvoiceCode'    => $invcode,
    'InvoiceDate'    => $request->InvoiceDate,
    'TotalPrice'     => $request->TotalPrice,
    'CustomerName'   => $request->CustomerName,
    'CustomerPhone'  => $request->CustomerPhone,
    'CustomerEmail'  => $request->CustomerEmail,
    'CustomerAddress'=> $request->CustomerAddress,
];
```

But the `$invnum` is only 1 digit, and I need like 00001 when the 1st Invoice is generated.

How do I create the invoice template? Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) PHP function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_pad to add the leading zeros.

```
$invnum = str_pad($invnum, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_pad` to pad a string.

```
str_pad($invnum, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```